# CSS Display an Image Resized and Cropped

Tags: html, css, background-image, image

I want to show an image from an URL with a certain width and height even if it has a different size ratio. 
So I want to resize (maintaining the ratio) and then cut the image to the size I want.

I can resize with html `img` property and I can cut with `background-image`.

How can I do both?

Example:

This image:

[image]

Has the size `800x600` pixels and I want to show like an image of `200x100` pixels

With `img` I can resize the image `200x150px`:

```
<img 
    style="width: 200px; height: 150px;" 
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg">
```

That gives me this:

```html
<img style="width: 200px; height: 150px;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg">
```

And with `background-image` I can cut the image `200x100` pixels.

```
<div 
    style="background-image:
           url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg'); 
    width:200px; 
    height:100px; 
    background-position:center;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Gives me:

```html
    <div style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg'); width:200px; height:100px; background-position:center;">&nbsp;</div>
```

How can I do both?

Resize the image and then cut it the size I want?

Answer (score 548, accepted):

You could use a combination of both methods eg.

```css
    .crop {
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .crop img {
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="crop">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg" alt="Donald Duck">
    </div>
```

You can use negative `margin` to move the image around within the `<div/>`.

Comment: Note that if you set position:relative on the contained image, you'll need to set position:relative on the containing div.  If you don't, I've found that IE won't actually clip the image.

Comment: also remove height from .crop img class

Comment: @waqar-alamgir It wouldn't work if you removed the height declaration

Comment: Also note that when using css to crop an image, the user still has to download the image. It might be better to use php and GD or another image editing library to resize and crop the image before sending it to the user. It all depends on what you want, loading the server or the users bandwidth.

Comment: Just a note for others: .crop height and width define where to slice the bottom-most and right-most part of the image. .crop img height and width will scale the image. .crop img margin will pan the image

Comment: @sanchothefat Suppose we don't know the image size. We need to specify the margin using Javascript. Right? So that can cause a flickering effect. Can you think of any other solution?

Comment: @Jeevan hide the image until your JS runs using visibility:hidden;

Comment: @collindo Yes. it will work if its like a single time render. Suppose you are rendering something in a SERP, which is search as you type. And you are using this to show images the search results. So each time you make visibility hidden the images will flicker.

Comment: @Jeevan it will work for any scenario if implemented well.  For example, render the image with a special class `js-hide-until-loaded` then remove that class when the image's onload event fires. `onload="doSomething(this); $(this).removeClass('js-hide-until-loaded')"`

Comment: @collindo My concern was initially making it visibility:hidden and then later making it visible onload. Since we are updating a div say every second it will cause a slight flicker. You can't makeout when a text flickers in a SERP but for images its different.

Comment: Is there any way to make the cropped image responsive? http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: @skibulk you'd just have to use percentage widths and perhaps a max-width on the image. The same approach should still apply

Answer (score 154):

With CSS3 it's possible to change the size of a `background-image` with [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size), fulfilling both goals at once.

There are [a bunch of examples](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) on [css3.info](http://www.css3.info).

[Implemented based on your example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbqcf/1/), using [donald_duck_4.jpg](http://img1.jurko.net/wall/paper/donald_duck_4.jpg). In this case, `background-size: cover;` is just what you want - it fits the `background-image` to cover the entire area of the containing `<div>` and clips the excess (depending on the ratio).

```css
.with-bg-size {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg');
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  /* Make the background image cover the area of the <div>, and clip the excess */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="with-bg-size">Donald Duck!</div>
```

[css3](/questions/tagged/css3) [background-image](/questions/tagged/background-image) [background-size](/questions/tagged/background-size)

Comment: Great solution, but one caveat is that it isn't compatible with IE <9 (If that matters to anyone anymore). Also, I wanted to mention, if you replace cover with contain for background-size, it will scale, but not crop the image.

Comment: For `<img />` tags, look at [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and related values from the [CSS Image Values and Replaced Content Module Level 3 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#the-object-fit).

Answer (score 135):

Did you try to use this?

```css
.centered-and-cropped { object-fit: cover }
```

I needed to resize image, center (both vertically and horizontally) and than crop it.

I was happy to find, that it could be done in a single css-line. 
Check the example here: http://codepen.io/chrisnager/pen/azWWgr/?editors=110

---

Here is the `CSS` and `HTML`code from that example:

```css
.centered-and-cropped { object-fit: cover }
```

```html
<h1>original</h1>
<img height="200" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3174/bear.jpg" alt="Bear">
    
<h1>object-fit: cover</h1>
<img class="centered-and-cropped" width="200" height="200" 
style="border-radius:50%" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3174/bear.jpg" alt="Bear">
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the easiest and most universal way to go - but it doesn't seem to work with IE :/ 

Find the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: CSS3 object-fit is not supported by IE11 or EDGE(14) http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: @eye-wonder it is supported in Edge 16, coming out soon. If its non critical and used sparingly, it could be used today

Comment: In CSS3, we can try either way img+object-fit or div+background-image. So far in my experience background-image can be used to fit more conditions.

Comment: As of now this is also supported by Edge (don't know since when though).

Comment: There is object-fit polyfill for IE9+ https://github.com/constancecchen/object-fit-polyfill/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 22):

```
.imgContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.imgContainer img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img src="imageSrc" />
</div>
```

The containing div with essentially crop the image by hiding the overflow.

Answer (score 14):

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 140px, 140px, 0px);
}
```

```
<img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140" />
```

Answer (score 14):

A small addition to the previous answers that includes `object-fit: cover`:

[object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position)

> You can alter the alignment of the replaced element's content object within the element's box using the object-position property.

```css
.trimmed-cover {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 177px;
  object-position: center 40%;
}
```

```html
<img class="trimmed-cover" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg">
```

[image: result.gif]

Answer (score 9):

Thanks sanchothefat.

I have an improvement to your answer. As crop is very tailored for every image, this definitions should be at the HTML instead of CSS.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
   <img src="img.jpg" alt="" style="margin:-30% 0px -10% 0px;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

> **`object-fit`** may help you, if you're playing with `<img>` tag

The below code will crop your image for you. You can play around with [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 337px;
}
```

Comment: It made my day - I could easily attach this to a slide in my slick slider carousel implementation - **plain IMG object solution** and not touching into the "slider plugin's code base"

Comment: that's the advantage of CSS :)

Answer (score 6):

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using the `clip-path` property:

> The clip-path property lets you clip an element to a basic shape or to
>   an SVG source.
>
> Note: The clip-path property will replace the deprecated clip
>   property.

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  clip-path: inset(30px 35px);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg">
```

More examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

Answer (score 5):

Live Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/de4Lt57z/

HTML:

```
<div class="crop">
  <img src="example.jpg" alt="..." />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .crop img{
      width:400px;
      height:300px;
      position: absolute;
      clip: rect(0px,200px, 150px, 0px);
      }
```

**Explanation:**
Here image is resized by width and height value of the image. And crop is done by clip property.

For details about clip property follow: 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/

Answer (score 4):

In the crop class, place the image size that you want to appear:

```
.crop {
    width: 282px;
    height: 282px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.crop span.img {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 282px;
    display: block;
}
```

The html will look like:

```
<div class="crop">
    <span class="img" style="background-image:url('http://url.to.image/image.jpg');"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<p class="crop"><a href="http://templatica.com" title="Css Templates">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="css template" /></a></p>
```

---

```css
.crop {
    float: left;
    margin: .5em 10px .5em 0;
    overflow: hidden; /* this is important */
    position: relative; /* this is important too */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
}
.crop img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -55px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are [services](http://blog.filestack.com/api/how-to-automatically-resize-fit-and-align-any-image-using-only-url-parameters/) like Filestack that will do this for you.

They take your image url and allow you to resize it using url parameters.  It is pretty easy.

Your image would look like this after resizing to 200x100 but keeping the aspect ratio

The whole url looks like this

```
https://process.filestackapi.com/AhTgLagciQByzXpFGRI0Az/resize=width:200/crop=d:[0,25,200,100]/https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPh0S.jpg
```

but the important part is just

```
resize=width:200/crop=d:[0,25,200,100]
```

[image]

Comment: nice plug maybe - but equally - an awesome service (no, I'm not paid to say this ;-) ) - I literally have just signed up and it's pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

You can put the img tag in a div tag and do both, but I would recommend against scaling images in the browser.  It does a lousy job most of the time because browsers have very simplistic scaling algorithms.  Better to do your scaling in Photoshop or ImageMagick first, then serve it up to the client nice and pretty.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is to create a server side script that will resize and crop a picture on the server end so it'll send less data across the interweb.

It's fairly trivial, but if anyone is interested, I can dig up and post the code (asp.net)

Comment: CGI is probably the most portable method (and bandwidth-efficient), unless the OP intends to allow the user to perform their own resizing and cropping via Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="crop">
    <img src="image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

```
.crop {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.crop img {
  width: 100%;
  /*Here you can use margins for accurate positioning of cropped image*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, try using `{  background-size: cover;
}` for the `<div>` maybe give the div a class say `<div class="example" style=url('../your_image.jpeg');>` so it becomes 
`div.example{
background-size: cover}`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this recently. I wanted to make a thumbnail-link to a NOAA graph. Since their graph could change at any time, I wanted my thumbnail to change with it. But there's a problem with their graph: it has a huge white border at the top, so if you just scale it to make the thumbnail you end up with extraneous whitespace in the document.

Here's how I solved it:

http://sealevel.info/example_css_scale_and_crop.html

First I needed to do a little bit of arithmetic. The original image from NOAA is 960 × 720 pixels, but the top seventy pixels are a superfluous white border area. I needed a 348 × 172 thumbnail, without the extra border area at the top. That means the desired part of the original image is 720 - 70 = 650 pixels high. I needed to scale that down to 172 pixels, i.e., 172 / 650 = 26.5%. That meant 26.5% of 70 = 19 rows of pixels needed to be deleted from the top of the scaled image.

So…

1. Set the height = 172 + 19 = 191 pixels:

   **height=191**
2. Set the bottom margin to -19 pixels (shortening the image to 172 pixels high):

   **margin-bottom:-19px**
3. Set the top position to -19 pixels (shifting the image up, so that the top 19 pixel rows overflow & are hidden instead of the bottom ones):

   **top:-19px**

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="…" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden">
<img width=348 height=191 alt=""
style="border:0;position:relative;margin-bottom:-19px;top:-19px"
src="…"></a>
```

As you can see, I chose to style the containing <a> tag, but you could style a <div>, instead.

One artifact of this approach is that if you show the borders, the top border will be missing. Since I use border=0 anyhow, that wasn't an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kodem's [Image Resize Service](https://kodem.io/documentation/3?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=493296&utm_campaign=imageresize). You can resize any image with just a http call. Can be used casually in the browser or used in your production app.

- Upload the image somewhere you prefer (S3, imgur etc.)
- Plug it into your dedicated API url (from our dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a tool called Croppie that can crop images...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.js"> </script>
<script src="https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/bower_components/exif-js/exif.js"> </script>

<style>
    #page {
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    #demo-basic {
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Crop Image Demo</h1>
<input id="upload" type="file" />
<br />
<div id="page">
<div id="demo-basic"></div>
</div>

<input id="upload-result" type="button" value="Crop Image"/>
<br />
<img id="cropped-result" src=""/>

<script>
    var $uploadCrop;       

    $("#upload").on("change", function () { readFile(this); show(); });

    $("#upload-result").on("click", function (ev) {
        $uploadCrop.croppie("result", {
            type: "canvas",
            size: "viewport"
        }).then(function (resp) {
            $("#cropped-result").attr("src", resp);
        });
    });

    function show() {
        $uploadCrop = $("#demo-basic").croppie({
            viewport: { width: 100, height: 100 },
            boundary: { width: 300, height: 300 },
            enableResize: true,
            enableOrientation: true,
            mouseWheelZoom: 'ctrl',
            enableExif: true
        });
    }

    function readFile(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
        
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $("#demo-basic").addClass("ready");
                $uploadCrop.croppie("bind", {
                    url: e.target.result
                }).then(function () {
                    console.log("jQuery bind complete");
                });
            
            }
        
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        else {
            alert("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```