# How to automatically crop and center an image

Tags: css

Given any arbitrary image, I want to crop a square from the center of the image and display it within a given square.

This question is similar to this: [CSS Display an Image Resized and Cropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped), but I don't know the size of the image so I can't use set margins.

Comment: Must the element be an image tag, or can it be a div with a background-image property?

Comment: as long as I can set the image through my templating system, it doesn't matter. kind of ugly, but I guess inline styles will work.

Answer (score 374, accepted):

One solution is to use a background image centered within an element sized to the cropped dimensions.

---

## Basic example

```css
.center-cropped {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-cropped" 
     style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/200');">
</div>
```

---

## Example with `img` tag

This version retains the `img` tag so that we do not lose the ability to drag or right-click to save the image. Credit to [Parker Bennett](http://css-tricks.com/crop-top/) for the opacity trick.

```css
.center-cropped {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Set the image to fill its parent and make transparent */
.center-cropped img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* modern browsers */
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-cropped" 
     style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/200');">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
</div>
```

---

## `object-fit`/`-position`

*[See supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).*

The [CSS3 Images specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/) defines the `object-fit` and `object-position` properties which together allow for greater control over the scale and position of the image content of an `img` element. With these, it will be possible to achieve the desired effect:

```css
.center-cropped {
  object-fit: none; /* Do not scale the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img class="center-cropped" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
```

Comment: @TomSawyer Yes, using background-image is not ideal. If it is important to have an img tag for SEO, screenreaders, or otherwise, you can include one and hide it visually. http://jsfiddle.net/WN2kT/

Comment: You can use `background-size: cover;` to get the image to shrink or fill the div appropriately while maintaining the original aspect ratio.

Comment: don't forget the background-repeat: no-repeat; if your image could be smaller (in height) that the height of your div

Comment: When using background-image you should add background-size:cover to properly size the cropped image:  See http://jsfiddle.net/bw6ct/

Comment: I've been told that nowdays Google knows about transparent and hidden images, so `img`'s `alt` ant `title` attributes will be lost for your SEO.

Comment: I used this solution (and the background-size:cover) from @KrisErickson to solve an issue with cropping non-square profile images into circular profile images - see [blog post with example css](http://www.wombling.com/coding/scaling-or-cropping-profile-images-into-circles-when-the-source-isnt-a-square/)

Comment: in webkit you can also use `object-fit: cover;` directly on the img tag which feels a bit more semantic.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the heads up. I edited the answer to add an example w/ `object-fit`. I used a value of `none` here to prevent images larger than the desired square from scaling down.

Comment: I used object-fit: cover to get my desired effect of not losing aspect ratio, covering the square, and cropping if needed

Comment: object-fit / position works perfectly for me - thank you!

Answer (score 90):

I was looking for a pure CSS solution using `img` tags (not the background image way).

I found this brilliant way to achieve the goal on [crop thumbnails with css](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/):

```
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.thumbnail img.portrait {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

It is similar to @Nathan Redblur's answer but it allows for portrait images, too.

Works like a charm for me. The only thing you need to know about the image is whether it is portrait or landscape in order to set the `.portrait` class so I had to use a bit of Javascript for this part.

Comment: Just be aware that CSS transforms are only available in IE 9 and above.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: OP said "arbitrary image" so wouldn't know up-front if the image was taller than it was wide.

Comment: If you put min-height:100%;min-width:100%; instead of height:100%;width:auto; you don't need img.portrait class.

Comment: best solution combined with @user570605 suggestion

Comment: In WordPress you'll also need to add `max-width: none;` to `.thumbnail img`

Answer (score 69):

Try this: Set your image crop dimensions and use this line in your CSS:

```
object-fit: cover;
```

Comment: not very well supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit EDIT: actually, as usual, just MS browsers fail at this... it does represent quite a chunk of usage though :/

Comment: This does exactly what I need :)

Comment: The only widely used browsers that don't support this are Internet Explorer 11 and Edge. Depending on your audience, support right now is probably around 85-90%, which might make this viable for some scenarios.

Comment: king! awesome solution!!

Comment: ther's a good tutorial about that: https://medium.com/@chrisnager/center-and-crop-images-with-a-single-line-of-css-ad140d5b4a87

Comment: There is a polyfill for IE9+ https://www.npmjs.com/package/objectFitPolyfill

Comment: works great in 2021.

Answer (score 24):

## Example with `img` tag but without `background-image`

This solution retains the `img` tag so that we do not lose the ability to drag or right-click to save the image but without `background-image` just center and crop with css.

Maintain the aspect ratio fine except in very hight images. (check the link)

[(view in action)](http://jsfiddle.net/vYdBt/452/)

**Markup**

```
<div class="center-cropped">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
</div>
```

​
**CSS**

```
div.center-cropped {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div.center-cropped img {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Try this one... if image is smaller than the container it will center, otherwise it will crop http://jsfiddle.net/3ts4rm24/1/

Comment: Why do you use `left: 50%` with `transform: translateX(-50%)`?

Comment: `left` is a position related to the container
`translate` is related to the element
if your container is 100px, and your picture is 20px, `left` will put the picture between the position 50px-70px. To fix that we rest the size of the picture with `translateX(-50%)` and then your picture will be between 40px-60px.
Ej: if your container is 100px, `left: 50%` of this container 

rightMiddle = container/2 - element/2

Answer (score 9):

I created an angularjs directive using @Russ's and @Alex's answers

Could be interesting in 2014 and beyond :P

html

```
<div ng-app="croppy">
  <cropped-image src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="100" height="100"></cropped-image>
</div>
```

js

```
angular.module('croppy', [])
  .directive('croppedImage', function () {
      return {
          restrict: "E",
          replace: true,
          template: "<div class='center-cropped'></div>",
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var width = attrs.width;
              var height = attrs.height;
              element.css('width', width + "px");
              element.css('height', height + "px");
              element.css('backgroundPosition', 'center center');
              element.css('backgroundRepeat', 'no-repeat');
              element.css('backgroundImage', "url('" + attrs.src + "')");
          }
      }
  });
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pferdefleisch/Q7HNj/1/)

Comment: Hiya downvoters. Please leave a comment so I can update my answer if there is a mistake. I don't like giving false info. Cheers.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but this is not an Angular question and your answer is irrelevant. @pferdefleisch

Comment: @mburn that makes sense. It has been 3 years and this probably looks a little out of place or obnoxious now. I'll leave it up though because the upvotes on my comment tell me at least a couple people may find it useful (or they just don't like downvotes without comments).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#yourElementId
{
    background: url(yourImageLocation.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Keep in mind that `width` and `height` will only work if your DOM element has layout (a block displayed element, like a `div` or an `img`). If it is not (a span, for example), add `display: block;` to the CSS rules. If you do not have access to the CSS files, drop the styles inline in the element.

Comment: in most case, this CSS is used repeatedly with different images. therefore, it is inevitable to set the background image inline.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can crop image centered:

```
.thumbnail{position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 320px; height: 640px;}
.thumbnail img{
    position: absolute; top: -999px; bottom: -999px; left: -999px; right: -999px;
    width: auto !important; height: 100% !important; margin: auto;
}
.thumbnail img.vertical{width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;}
```

The only thing you will need is to add class "vertical" to vertical images, you can do it with this code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('img').one('load', function () {
        var $img = $(this);
        var tempImage1 = new Image();
        tempImage1.src = $img.attr('src');
        tempImage1.onload = function() {
            var ratio = tempImage1.width / tempImage1.height;
            if(!isNaN(ratio) && ratio < 1) $img.addClass('vertical');
        }
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
});
```

Note: "!important" is used to override possible width, height attributes on img tag.

Answer (score 0):

for something like instagram explore or grid use this on img tag

```
aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; //or whatever
object-fit: cover;
```

note that parent has to have display of grid

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33906542)

Answer (score 0):

Best of two worlds, some resize and then some croop, by double flexbox around image. Suitable to use for a full screen image (I use it for an image carousel) The width: 100vw and height: 100vh for container is the magic css.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://someimageurl.jpg" 
   alt="image" class="image">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }
 
 .slide {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 max-width: 1600px;
 max-height: 1000px;
 justify-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 .image {
 display: block;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover; /* Cover the image */
 object-position: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 }
```