# Display thumbnail of 100x100 with centered image vertically and horizontally with css keeping the aspect ratio

Tags: image, css, thumbnails

I want to display an image in 100x100 thumbnail which will be centered vertically and horizontally keeping the aspect ratio and it must be filled in 100x100 thumbnail div e.g. an image of 800x600 must be displayed vertically filled and horizontally overflowed from both sides. How can I do this with css ?

Comment: We would like to help, but please do show us what you have tried &mdash; then we can help to improve on your implementation. Without code, our hands are tied.

Comment: I didn't tried anything yet

Comment: We can't help until you have attempted at something - or anything. We avoid spoon-feeding users.

Comment: Similar question: ["How to automatically crop and centre an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552380/how-to-automatically-crop-and-center-an-image). See also the `background-size` CSS property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some painting programs like photoshop please make some photo and show as all how you wanna to do it. Maybe we will know how to help cuz know i don't get it what you want.
If you only wanna align image on center on css use margin:50% 50%; It gives you X - center and Y - center + it depends if it's position:absolute; or relative...
For example:

```
<div style="width:400px;hegiht:500px;">
<img src="bla.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin: 50% 50%;" /> // It only will be centered in this Div only!
</div>
```