# HTML - Bootstrap - How to crop the center part of an image

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, crop

I'm creating a website and I want to crop an image to a square image based on the orientation of the image. I'm not really familiar with CSS so I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.

If it's a landscape image (800x500) then I want the cropped image to be like this (500x500):

[image: Cropping 800x500 image]

If it's portrait (400x600) then it should crop out this part (400x400) of the image:

[image: Cropping 400x600 image]

How should I go about to achieve this? Preferably a method I can use along with Bootstrap's "img-responsive" so I can resize the cropped when needed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@FljpFl0p fix it [jsfiddle][1]

[1]: https://www.bootply.com/92024 and there is another answer here [How to automatically crop and center an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552380/how-to-automatically-crop-and-center-an-image). Tks!

If you want it responsive and using bootstrap 4. Try this one:

**CSS**

```
.thumb-post img {
  object-fit: none; /* Do not scale the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class img-responsive to img tag, which will scale your image and keep width / height ratio. If you are not satisfied with the results I would try using Javascript.

Comment: img-responsive will only rescale the image horizontally to the size of it's container, there's no restriction to the height of the image.

Comment: I guess you have to use the Javascript for this. You can restrict the height with max-height property, but in your case it is useless.

Comment: Yes, using max-height and overflow:hidden would help me to crop the image to the size I want, only problem is that it will always be the top of the image.

Comment: @FljpFl0p try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teleginzhenya/0rhjwjjg/) if you don't fix smth :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are pretty limited to a CSS approach only, but a JavaScript approach would help by getting the image's dimension and wrapping it with in a div with `overflow:hidden`.

```js
$width = $(".box img").css('width');
$height = $(".box img").css('height');
$max = (($width < $height) ? $width : $height);

$(".box").css("width", $max);
$(".box").css("height", $max);
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lifesaver from @Állan Fidelis Toledo

One might find it useful to use '**contain**' on the css '**object-fit**' to keep the aspect ratio of the image.
By setting max-height it is useful in Bootstrap 4 as well. Works on all 'col' classes in Bootstrap 4.

```
.thumb-post img {
  object-fit: contain; /* keep aspect ratio */
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 147px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```