# image cropping with css to keep proper scale effect

Tags: html, css

I have different images and I want to keep them in a same height and width.

### My code structure is:

```
<figure>
    <img src="..img/image.png" />
</figure>
```

I have about four of these elements.

### My css are:

```
figure{
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 200px;
}

.thumbnail figure img {
  max-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
```

This is helping me to keep the same height and width.

### But the problem is:

If i place a image with large pixel ratio it looks large. For example, if I use a pic with a man with high resolution, it shows only the eyes and nose.

What can I do now?

Comment: resize (reduce overall image pixels) the image in `mspaint` and save

Comment: Can you produce the same effect in jsfiddle

Comment: @odedta i know that but i dont want to resize image

Comment: @odedta that's a really bad solution for this problem. And `mspaint` come one...

Comment: Are all your pictures landscape ? Or portrait ?

Comment: What's wrong with mspaint? and how is that a bad solution? if the image height is 200px, why cram a 3000 pixels image into it?

Comment: @muhaimin have you tried giving it a `width` in `%`? like `width:30%`. I think you have to declare a `width` tag on your image so it will re-size it.

Comment: If you can use it in a background image, use `background-size: cover;` http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: How about a fixed `height: 200px` (and `display: block`)? You keep the ratio and it will scale. The overflow can handle larger widths. Perhaps a `text-align: center;` to finalize it.

Comment: @TimVermaelen not working with `height:200px` and `display:block` :(

Comment: @BramDriesen yes i have tried with % but not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically crop and center an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552380/how-to-automatically-crop-and-center-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be useful to you.

give the max-height: 200px just as you like. suppose if your normal image has dimensions 400X400(in pixels), you can crop the image to 200px but you are saying that is fine. Your problem starts with images with higher resolution. In this case you give max-width of figure to 200px and lower the height and width of the image than the original size. Suppose your image has dimensions 800X800(in pixels), reduce width and height of the image, say (width: 400px; height: 400px;), then you may see atleast face instead of only having nose or eyes. If you want to see more part of image, you should  reduce the size of image much lower.

But i suggest you to compress the image if u have high resolution images.      (http://www.resize-photos.com/)

I think it should work.
Please post the result if this doesn't works

```
figure{
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 200px;
}

.thumbnail figure img {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: (lower than original width);
  height: (lower than original height);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution to your problem, if you specify the max-width for the img separate it will constrain very large images from becoming useable

```
figure{
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 200px;
}

.thumbnail figure {
  max-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
 }

 img {
   max-height: 500px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jwyjwrej/