# Auto image cropping

Tags: javascript, html, css

Setting up a CMS that I would like to automatically restrict images uploaded, without distorting nor setting the image as a background, as I want site visitors to be able to copy the image. Can this be done in css or javascript?

```
<div class="outer">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CMIQjovvgcQ/VOy4zOpkW3I/AAAAAAAAAH4/8cE_5moqRFQ/s1600/happy%2Bholi%2Bphotos.jpg" width="100%"/>
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150218160918-stress-super-169.jpg" width="100%"/>
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02951/photoshopping-peg_2951334k.jpg" width="100%"/>
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

css

```
.outer{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:3%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tonytansley/9y09b4hh/ is a crude example of the problem.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what the actual problem is?

Comment: So, what is the question exactly?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for cropping script? Lots of google results for "javascript image crop" and "jquery image crop"

Comment: I don't want users uploading images all different shapes and sizes, but ultimately they will. So I want a way of 'Auto image cropping' so they will all be the same dimensions

Comment: Just looking for something simple to administer this automatically. Prefer a css solution, but simple javascript would be ok

Comment: Please see this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11552460/85125) for possible CSS solutions. Also, the `ruby-on-rails` tag is unnecessary, please remove it.

Comment: The [tag:ruby-on-rails] is there because I am integrating into ruby-on-rails and would welcome a solution in that medium. The link you have added does seem to be along the same lines as mine, although there doesn't seem to be any 100% supported answers. Best I will get though I suppose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in short, it seems that the only way to currently achieve this solution is with background-image and background-size:cover on a pre-sized div.

What looks promising (although not fully supported) is the following...

```
.center-cropped {
  object-fit: none; /* Do not scale the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

and

```
<img class="center-cropped" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
```

But until then, the background-image is the best (albeit non-SEO friendly) way to do it.