# crop and center image by css

Tags: html, css, image

I have multiple images which have a size of 2000px by 2000px. I want to put them into square 500px by 500px. And I want to crop the images so that about 10% of the image at each border would not be visible. (Like taking 80% by 80% of the picture at the center)

How do I do that? The solution below would crop the image too much.

background-position: center center;

[How to automatically crop and center an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552380/how-to-automatically-crop-and-center-an-image)

Comment: can you create a demo with what you tried sofar?

Comment: @G.L.P You can find the code of my website here. [link](http://expfood.ru). For this you need to click on reactangular image on the right to see items. And then on any item's image (such as bananas). The bigger image is the one I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Example

Use div for this

```
<div >
 <img src="" ></img>

 </div>
```

css

```
   div{

    position:absolute
    Height:500px;
    width:400px;

    }

 img{
     position:relative;
    Height:300px;//give some width n height to image
    width:200px;
   margin:10px;    
    }
```