# how to get an image to crop in center

Tags: html, css, image, crop, image-resizing

I made my post thumbnail images of full width and responsive. Because they were so tall, I gotthem cropped at 600px. The problem is that as the screen gets bigger the images crop at the top, not in the center of the image as I want it. Is there any way to make the images crop in the center?
I don't want to use `background-image` here.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e6p2byh/).

```css
.large-front-thumbnail {
position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.large-front-container {
    max-height:600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="large-front-container">
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2855/landscape-mountains-nature-lake.jpg" class="large-front-thumbnail">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.large-front-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* add this line to move your picture 50% up*/
}
```

To use in all browsers:

```
     transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
```

But I'd suggest you to use `background-image` case described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552380/how-to-automatically-crop-and-center-an-image)