# CSS to display image preview better

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to figure out what is the best, if it can be done, and desired method to take an image that is uploaded and trim the image for a thumb in CSS.  If it cannot be done in pure CSS what is the method to do it in JavaScript/jQuery?  The images may be different sizes but I am looking for a way that an image will **square on center**, and then reduce to fit.  Example below:

This image is 413 x 300.

[image]

If this image was trimmed from the left and right for the portfolio thumb it would be 300 X 300:

[image]

Then the image needs to be reduced for the thumb 200 x 200 or what ever value the thumb is set to display:

[image]

**EDIT**
my understanding if `#img_preview{width:200px;}` is applied it would result in this:

[image]

Comment: AFAIK it's something that should be done server-side. Even a raw image processing is terribly slow in JavaScript (by the way...how can you access the image data?)

Comment: The images will be uploaded through a submission form for a board.  I am using a drag and drop HTML5 uploader.

Comment: This is easiest if you can change the HTML and wrap it in a container `<div>`, or better yet, use it as a background image for that `<div>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped

Comment: @graphicdivine would that crop the image on center though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/cnWqQ/5/

css like this:

```
#img-wrap{
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ1j8.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center; 
}
```

html like so:

```
<div id="img-wrap"></div>
```

Works by putting the images as the background in a div, works for all image shapes and sizes consistently.

it involves some css3.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in CSS, but it will only work with modern browsers :

You'll use `background-image` property :

```
<div id="myImageTrimed">
</div>
```

and the css :

```
#myImageTrimed {
    background-image: url('img/youImage.jpg');
    background-position: center; /* to make sure it trims the borders */
    background-size: cover; /* As large as possible */
    height: 200px; /* But only 200x200px are shown */
    width: 200px;
}
```

Please comment if you have more browser constraints.

Comment: Have you actually tried this out? it leads to a stretched image.

Comment: Because the image background-size should not be set to 300px 300px if it's not square. Either you can put percentage (eg: 80% 80%) or you can calculate height pixel dimensions to make sure height is 200px;

Comment: cool, I didn't know the background-size: cover property ! I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the CSS `width` to the value you need, the height will be automatically adjusted to maintain the aspect ratio.

```
#img_preview{
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't center the image correct and in result cut off 100px to the right?

Comment: look at the edit.  This method would only change starting from `0,0`

Comment: No, that is not what it does. Question: do you want to resize the image or crop the image? Crop is not the same as resize. The last image in your edit will be the output of crop.

Answer (score 0):

You can mask the image with a `div`:

Your div:
`height:200px;
     width:200px;
     overflow: hidden;`

Your image:
     `position:absolute;
     height:inherit;
     margin-left:-15%;`

see this demo below: http://jsfiddle.net/jRCgP/