# How to display image height according to device css

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is with my image. The img height is 1500px. That need to scroll down. I want the height to be as the height of the device display,  like mobile and computer display.

```
img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle does not require a user account.

Comment: You don't need an account in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Display an Image Resized and Cropped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped)

Comment: can image height is change according to device. i give height 100%, and it's scroll down

Answer (score 0):

make the height also `100%`

```
img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: but height is not changed according the device. My image size is 1500px, it give me to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a wrapper with `height: 100%;`;
add same `height: 100%;` to the `.img` tag.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BgR3j/)