# image cropping with CSS

Tags: css, resize

How do you crop the image with CSS/coding? Or how can I find tutorials on it?

So I don't want the image to be resized, but to be "cut off"

Comment: I think you are talking about image size, not the html `<canvas>` element, right?

Comment: I'm indeed talking about image size!

Comment: That's too board. Can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: You could place the image in a div with hidden overflow.. You can't literally crop an image with CSS.

Comment: You could search it in Google.

Comment: Please provide what you've tried, and let us know what your expected result is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/493329/2134604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the image itself will not zoom if you do not apply `width` or `height` attribute/style on it.

resize the container, apply `height` and `width` style on it, together with `overflow:hidden`.

example:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://example.com/some-image.png" alt="example"/>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.image-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

further, if you want to adjust position of the image, apply `position: relative` and `top` `bottom` `left` `right` on it:

```
.image-container img {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: -50px;
}
```