# How can I display different shaped images uniformly with CSS/PHP/Jquery?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

I'm working on a wordpress site with ~150 posts, each with a featured image. The featured images are not the same dimensions. I want to display a grid of these images but the different shapes (some horizontal rectangle, some square, some vertical rectangle) mess up the uniformity of the grid. How can I display the images to be all the same size (cropping is ok) using php, css, or jquery/javascript?

For instance, lets say all images are at least 300 x 300, but some are 450 x 300, some are 400 x 400, some are 300 x 450. I want them all to display as 300 x 300, and cropping is ok.  Can I do this with a wordpress query? Some php/css/javascript?

Comment: Might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped

Comment: Do you need to use this with `<img` or would it also be possible to use these images as div-backgrounds ?