# How can you do disappear the background of an image?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website created in MVC4.

I have an image. And I only want to show the shape (an arrow) of the image. And I don't want to show the rest of the image (the background).

[image]   <= only the white background of the arrows has to be disappeared.

How do you do that?

I tried this, but with this the whole image will disappear, in stead of a part of it:

```
.images_top {
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: top;
     -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
       filter: alpha(opacity=0);
       opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: In Delphi this is a possibility.

Comment: I think that will answer on you question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped

Comment: could you provide a working demo to replicate this issue? (for example, you're talking about an image, but I don't see an image in your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you can use a PNG with alpha channel.

If this is not possible look at this tutorial about how to clip images by using the SVG clip-path.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Even though it is possible only in recent browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use PNG Images for Transparent Background. You can use any online converter to convert your image to PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the now better supported `PNG` (and `PNG8` with better fallback-support (looking at IE) and a (configurable) transparent color (index from the pallette) instead of alpha, pretty much just like `GIF`), there is also `GIF` which has 'always' been supported (and is no longer cumbered with legal issues, which were only due to it's LZW based compression-algorithm, that one can bypass).

Because of the lack of alpha-channel, creating nice transparent PNG8 and GIF images (without the dreaded overly visual grainy (often white) borders) is somewhat of a true art, infact pixel-art.
The *trick* is to touch-up the borders between color and transparancy by hand AND to set the image's background-color (when rendering from alpha channel to single color-index transparancy) to the *average* color of the background the images are going to be used against.

The idea of fatter png's is that they have alpha-channels which will give you (for clear example) nice shades (if you had applied such an effect) that will blend with *any* background. Now with modern browsers, this works pretty nice (and doesn't require the pixel-art). Pixel-art PNG8/GIF can still have it's place though, for base64 encoded ui-elements, usually small icons.