# CSS - Aspect Fill image

Tags: html, css, image

How do you resize an image (using plain old HTML and CSS - no JavaScript) so that it fills a given size even if some of the image is lost?

Essentially what I'm looking for is `Aspect Fill` on iOS.

i.e. if IMAGE is too wide, you'd just see what's between the square brackets below:

```
IM[AG]E
```

i.e. `AG`. The same would happen if it was too high.

E.g. assuming I'm using something like this: `<img src="" />`

Comment: Do you mean in inline image <img src=" etc. or using background-image as a css property. It is possible with the latter.

Comment: I meant using <img  src="">. Is it not possible with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to show the image as the background of an element, for instance:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background: transparent url('image.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;"></div>
```