# CSS image centering

Tags: html, css

I have a small block and image width larger than the block. I want to block center equals image center.

Image center and block center must be on 1 vertical line. And i want to see only central part of image.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7gk07eLm/ - this my attempt

Comment: That's not a question, what do you expect us to do with this? Please edit your question and provide some code samples.

Comment: Could you please provide your code?.

Comment: whats the expected output

Comment: Image crop like CSS for example you can see [CSS Display an Image Resized and Cropped](http://stackoverflow.com/a/493329/5569496)

Comment: in output i want to see only central part of image with parent block width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of use negative margin on your image, you can use the `transform` property

```
.img-container{
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.img-container img{
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7gk07eLm/2/

Comment: Thank you! Great solution for my task)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

html

```
<div class="img-container">
    </div>
```

css:

```
enter code here
.img-container{
 max-width: 100px;
 min-height: 580px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-image: url(http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. Instead of `<img>` tag you can use background css property with background-position set to center, and with background-size set to cover, on `<div>`; in your case it's going to be something like this:

   `.img-container {`
   `width: 100px;`
   `height: 500px;`
   `background: no-repeat center /cover url("path_to_your_image");`
   `}`

Height property must be set!

2. If you want to stick with `<img>` tag it's going to look something like this:

   `.img-container {`
    `width: 100px;`
     `height: 500px;`
     `overflow: hidden;`
     `position: relative;`
   `}`

   `.img-container img {`
    `position: absolute;`
     `right: -1000%;`
     `left: -1000%;`
     `top: -1000%;`
     `bottom: -1000%;`
     `margin: auto;`
   }

The crazy numbers in right, left, top and bottom positions for image are because of small size of parent `<div>` and big size of image itself - the percentage is based on width and height of parent block, so in this case `right: 100%;` will be 100px, that's why you need bigger numbers for positioning a much larger image in a smaller parent block.

Values can be tweaked, of course, as long as they are equal image will be centered.

**In both cases height must be set, or it won't work!**