# Crop image to be a stripe on bigger screens

Tags: css, image, media, crop, clip

All my images should be responsive so i defined image width 100%. But most of the pictures are getting too big on a bigger screen than the iPhone. 
These images don't need to have full height so i want them to be stripes.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for are css media queries.

As an example:

```
img {width: 50%;}

@media only screen
and (max-device-width : 767px)
{
img {width: 100%;}
}
```

This will make your images 50% width on a desktop, but on a mobile device with a screen of 767px or less the images will be 100% width.

Comment: I tried media query and clip before but i dont get stripe like images. What about the height in your code?

Comment: @koolguy  You can use the method defined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped to set up the image as you want it for desktop, then override that for the mobile view.