# crop GIF images without loosing animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

Is there any way to maintain animation after cropping Gif image.i can able to crop gif images https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/ but the animation is lost after crop is done.is it possible to maintain animation?any examples Thanks.

Comment: You can put it as a background and clip the container

Comment: Hey Thank you,can you provide an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped

Comment: but that does not resize it into cropped width and height