How to crop a image?
my project
This is my first time making a website, I have searched the internet and watched videos but it doesn't work for me.
Im trying to make this image look good and cropped but i'm not sure how. It's just stretched out please any advice. I just need it a little cropped on the bottom. It has to be horizontal and fit across the page.
I dont know if im supposed to use height? I tried it and it doesn't crop the image as I want.

What have you tried? Does this article help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/493296/18667225

You can try the object-fit property in CSS, to control how the image is scaled and filled within a container element. To crop a bit from the bottom, you can combine this with a container that has a specific height. Here's an example of how you could do this:

HTML:

<div class="image-container">
    <img src="path/to/your/image.jpg" alt="Image Description">
</div>


CSS:

    .image-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px; /* adjust as needed to crop the image */
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .image-container img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }


